# After install fog gem server won't start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, server, carrierwave, fog

I installed carrierwave gem and fog gem to use Amazon s3. However, after following all the steps, I tried to run `rails s -p $PORT -b $IP` because I am using cloud9. The server does not start! FYI, I am using postgresql as my database.

Here's part of the error:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.5 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- fog (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.0.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:121:in `eager_load_fog'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.0.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:136:in `fog_credentials='
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.0.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:158:in `configure'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.0.0/lib/carrierwave.rb:14:in `configure'
```

here my image_uploader:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base


  storage :fog
  # storage :fog
  include CarrierWave :MimeTypes
  process :set_content_type


  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end


end
```

my `carrierwave.rb`:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:              'AWS',                        # required
    aws_access_key_id:     ENV["S3_ACCESS_KEY"],                        # required
    aws_secret_access_key: ENV["S3_SECRET_KEY"]                      # required
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV["S3_BUCKET"]                          # required
end
```

Edit

Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.5)
      actionpack (= 4.2.5)
      actionview (= 4.2.5)
      activejob (= 4.2.5)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.5)
      actionview (= 4.2.5)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (4.2.5)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    activejob (4.2.5)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.5)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.5)
      activemodel (= 4.2.5)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.5)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    acts_as_votable (0.10.0)
    arel (6.0.4)
    autoprefixer-rails (6.6.1)
      execjs
    bcrypt (3.1.11)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bootstrap-sass (3.3.7)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.2.1)
      sass (>= 3.3.4)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (9.0.6)
    carrierwave (1.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 4.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    climate_control (0.1.0)
    cocaine (0.5.8)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.1.x)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.4)
    css_convertor (1.0.3)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    devise (4.2.0)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0, < 5.1)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    font-awesome-rails (4.7.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.1)
    globalid (0.3.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    haml (4.0.7)
      tilt
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.6.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.2.2)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (5.0.5)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    json (1.8.6)
    kaminari (0.17.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.4)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4)
    mime-types (3.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
    mimemagic (0.3.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
    minitest (5.10.1)
    multi_json (1.12.1)
    nested_form (0.3.2)
    nokogiri (1.7.0.1)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.1.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    paperclip (5.1.0)
      activemodel (>= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.5)
      mime-types
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.0)
    pg (0.18.4)
    rack (1.6.5)
    rack-pjax (1.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)
      rack (>= 1.1)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.5)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.5)
      actionpack (= 4.2.5)
      actionview (= 4.2.5)
      activejob (= 4.2.5)
      activemodel (= 4.2.5)
      activerecord (= 4.2.5)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.5)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.8)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails-i18n (4.0.9)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      railties (~> 4.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_admin (1.1.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      coffee-rails (~> 4.0)
      font-awesome-rails (>= 3.0, < 5)
      haml (~> 4.0)
      jquery-rails (>= 3.0, < 5)
      jquery-ui-rails (~> 5.0)
      kaminari (~> 0.14)
      nested_form (~> 0.3)
      rack-pjax (>= 0.7)
      rails (>= 4.0, < 6)
      remotipart (~> 1.3)
      sass-rails (>= 4.0, < 6)
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.5)
    railties (4.2.5)
      actionpack (= 4.2.5)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (12.0.0)
    rdoc (4.3.0)
    remotipart (1.3.1)
    responders (2.3.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.1)
    sass (3.4.23)
    sass-rails (5.0.6)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sdoc (0.4.2)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    simple_form (3.4.0)
      actionpack (> 4, < 5.1)
      activemodel (> 4, < 5.1)
    spring (2.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    sprockets (3.7.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (0.19.4)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (2.0.5)
    turbolinks (5.0.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5)
    turbolinks-source (5.0.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (3.0.4)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    warden (1.2.6)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    web-console (2.3.0)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  acts_as_votable (~> 0.10.0)
  autoprefixer-rails
  bootstrap-sass (~> 3.3, >= 3.3.7)
  byebug
  carrierwave (~> 1.0)
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  css_convertor (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
  devise (~> 4.2)
  haml (~> 4.0, >= 4.0.7)
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  paperclip (~> 5.1)
  pg (~> 0.18.2)
  rails (= 4.2.5)
  rails-i18n (~> 4.0, >= 4.0.8)
  rails_12factor
  rails_admin (~> 1.0)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  simple_form (~> 3.3, >= 3.3.1)
  spring
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (~> 2.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.3.0p0

BUNDLED WITH
   1.12.5
```

that's my Initializers/Carrierwave.rb:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider => 'AWS',                        # required
    :aws_access_key_id  =>   ENV["S3_ACCESS_KEY"],                        # required
    :aws_secret_access_key => ENV["S3_SECRET_KEY"]                      # required
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV["S3_BUCKET"]                          # required
end
```

Let me know if more info is needed, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the sections of your Gemfile where `fog` is referenced? Is it also referenced in the Gemfile.lock?

Comment: @tompave I just add it, check it out please

Comment: I added it manually through the terminal, `gem install fog`

Comment: That's why it wasn't working. Installing it with `gem install` does not automatically add it to the application bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `fog` is not listed in your `Gemfile.lock`.

Ensure to add this at the root level of your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'fog', '~> 1.38'
```

Then run:

```
bundle install
```

and commit the changes.

Restart the app, it should work.

Comment: That's what I am getting now
`Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/fog-core-1.43.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:244:in `validate_options': Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key (ArgumentError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/fog-core-1.43.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:268:in `handle_settings'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/fog-core-`

Comment: Ok, so the issue you reported has been solved. The new error you're getting is a completely different issue. You need to make sure your `ENV` contains the variables you're referencing.

Comment: can you tell me how to do so please?

Comment: I also added my initializer to see if it has any issue with it?

Comment: You had already posted it. I think that you should start [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/ENV.html), then google how to work with unix environment variables.